# making a custom image frame in css by overlapping divs, but not being able to access the image anymore

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a custom, irregular frame for a google maps iframe. You can see my results so far here:

http://bufident.com/pruebas/site02/contacto/contacto.html

(please forgive the sloppy markup)
The only way I could think up of doing this was by having 1 div with the frame overlapping the div with the map like this

```
        <div style="width:418px; height: 375px;position:relative;top:-375px;z-index:3;">
        <iframe width="418" height="375" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=bufident&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=40.397236,-3.704112&amp;sspn=0.071946,0.071946&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;view=map&amp;cid=5584215307643134377&amp;hq=bufident&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.397238,-3.704109&amp;spn=0.006128,0.008948&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Unfortunately, if i do this i'm no longer able to interact with the map. I tried a slightly different method suggested in another thread ( http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/11/css-cookie-cutter-revisited.html ) but i get the same results
Any suggestions? thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 4 images instead of one.. The div holding the images must be under the iframe, and the images above.. So you need absolute positioning for it.. That way the overlapping images are more border-like..

Also there is another solution that allows clicking through div's, found that in a jquery plugin. I'll check if I can find it..

**EDIT**

Here is a site which explains how cliking through divs works:

http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You are laying the DIV on top of the map, so you the Google Maps Javascript, won't detect clicks / interactions with it because you are actually clicking the DIV, rather than the map.

Don't think what you are trying to achieve would be possible. Best compromise I can see is to have the rough border on the outside of the box, but keep the inner edge of the border still a square. Set the background image on the parent DIV, and position the map in the middle of your div, on top. Something like this...

```
<div style="background:url(image.jpg); padding:20px">
  <iframe />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah duh, or as @Tim says, split the border into its four sides, crop the images as tight as you can make them, and lay them ontop.